# Convert string to integer on Windows Batch

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, integer

I've been searching a lot about how to convert a string into a integer on windows batch but I just can't get how to do it.

I've written a batch that copies a file from a directory to another and name it after the current date. My code goes something like this:

`set FILE=log %date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%
copy C:\log.txt C:\"%FILE%".txt`

I need to do the conversion to make FILE be one day previous.
For example, if I run the script right now, I'll get a file named "log 2014-07-09", but I want it to be "log 2014-07-08".

I've tried with this few sentences but I get an error about the numeric value is not valid:

```
set DAY=%date:~0,2% :: this assignation give me no problems
set /A DAY = %DAY%-1 :: this is the one that makes my head breaks
```

I don't know where the error is because I barely know windows batch sentences. I've read about the SET command syntax at Help command and other sites (like [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php) one) but I can't get where I'm failing. I know this may be very simple (on some programming languages a Parse sentence would be enough), but I'm a total novice on this batch script stuff, so any help will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: [The curse of the leading zero](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/16/10490109.aspx).

Comment: PowerShell would make all of this a whole lot simpler: `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" -f (get-date).AddDays(-1)`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what PowerShell is.

Comment: You copy command is wrong. 1/ Remove the quotes around %file%. 2/ %file% equate to `log /07/- 1-Th` so your copy command is `copy C:\log.txt C:\"log /07/- 1-Th".txt`. That does not look right.

Comment: "I don't know what PowerShell is" -- [what is PowerShell?](http://www.google.com/search?&q=what+is+powershell)

Comment: Will this be executed the fist day of month? The previous day will fall in the previous month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to resolve it :

```
@echo off 
set "$DateNew=%date:~0,2%"
set /a "$DateNew=%$DateNew:0=%-1"
if %$DateNew%==0 set "$DateNew=10"
set "$DateNew=0%$DateNew%"
set "FILE=log %date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%$dateNew:~-2%"

copy C:\log.txt C:\"%FILE%.txt"
```

Comment: `set /a $DateNew=%$DateNew:0=%-1` If today is `10`, the final value is `0`

Comment: Oops ! Corrected Thanks @MC ND

Answer (score 0):

subtract one and keep a leading zero:

```
set a=08
set /a a=11%a%-1001
set a=%a:~1%
echo %a%
```

of course, `01`- `1` = `00`...

Answer (score 0):

All of the cmd shell script (batch) string-number parsing pain can be avoided in PowerShell:

```
copy-item C:\log.txt ("C:\{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" -f (get-date).AddDays(-1))
```

This also avoids the "last day of the month" problem. For example, the code

```
"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f (get-date "8/1/2014").AddDays(-1)
```

outputs `2014-07-31`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a robust way to get yesterday's date with a batch file:

```
:: get yesterdays date
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"

echo Yesterday was "%data%"
pause
```

Comment: Clever idea (create temporary VBScript script file). I still think PowerShell is easier...

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I like the idea of Powershell Bill, but it's crippled because every user has to jump through hoops to be able to run a powershell script.  if Microsoft had generated a prompt on running the first PS script to ask if they want to allow the script once, the script all the time, or allow all scripts in the future - then it would have been more useful.  As it stands the basic users don't have the skills to enable Powershell scripts.

Comment: It's not really too difficult. Open an elevated command window and enter the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. If the local user doesn't have administrator privileges, he/she can enter `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned CurrentUser`. The execution policy can also be set in a GPO.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It's not hard if you know how to do it. :)

Comment: Same as your VBScript workaround - easy if you know how. :) I would argue that PowerShell is a more valuable skill to learn from this point forward.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Not the same though - anyone can run the script without setting anything up beforehand.  If you don't know how to enable powershell then A) you have to find out and B) `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned CurrentUser` is a command that these people will have to blindly trust someone, because the command doesn't tell the basic user what it is going to allow.

Comment: Without getting into an extended discussion... 1) all shell scripts are "trusted" (at least PowerShell *can* be secured!), and 2) there is [documentation about PowerShell execution policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx), so it's not hard to tell exactly what it does.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart  Once again, it's not hard when you already know.